# Normal issues in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, modeling

We are trying, with a friend, to modelise a tree on unity. To do so, we want to modelise a tree trunk. We are doing it with the following code :
`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class Frustum : MonoBehaviour
{
    /*====== PUBLIC ======*/
    public float height = 1;
    public float top_radius = 0.9F;
    public float base_radius = 1F;
    public int circle_subdivisions = 30;

    /*====== PRIVATE ======*/
    private Mesh mesh;
    private Vector3[] vao;
    private int[] ibo;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.name = "Cone";

        this.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;

        draw();
    }

    // OnValidate is called at each public input change
    private void OnValidate() {
        draw();
    }

    private void draw() {
        ComputeFrustumVao();
        ComputeFrustumIbo();

        mesh.Clear();
        mesh.vertices = vao;
        mesh.triangles = ibo;
        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
        mesh.RecalculateTangents();
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
       // mesh.Optimize();
    }

    private void ComputeFrustumVao()
    {
        // COMPUTE BASE VERTICES
        List<Vector3> vertices = ComputeCircleVertices(transform.position, base_radius, circle_subdivisions);
    
        // ADD TOP VERTICES
        Vector3 top_origin = transform.position + new Vector3(0, height, 0);
        vertices.AddRange(ComputeCircleVertices(top_origin, top_radius, circle_subdivisions));
        
        vao = vertices.ToArray();
    }

    private List<Vector3> ComputeCircleVertices(Vector3 origin, float radius, int nb_subdivisions) {
        List<Vector3> vao = new List<Vector3>();
        float step_angle = (2*Mathf.PI)/nb_subdivisions;

        for(int i = 0; i < nb_subdivisions; ++i){
            float current_angle = step_angle * i;
            Vector3 translate_vector = new Vector3(
                Mathf.Cos(current_angle) * radius,  // x coordinate
                0,                                  // y coordinate
                Mathf.Sin(current_angle) * radius   // z coordinate
            );

            Vector3 new_vertex = origin + translate_vector;

            vao.Add(new_vertex);
        }

        return vao;
    }

    private void ComputeFrustumIbo() {
        List<int> indices = new List<int>();
        int nb_vertices = vao.Length;
        int nb_vertices_per_circle = nb_vertices/2;
        int nb_triangles =  nb_vertices_per_circle - 2;

        // DRAW BASE
        for(int i = 0; i < nb_triangles; ++i){
            indices.Add(0);
            indices.Add(i + 1);
            indices.Add(i + 2);
        }

        // DRAW TOP
        for(int i = nb_vertices_per_circle; i < nb_vertices_per_circle + nb_triangles; ++i){
            indices.Add(nb_vertices_per_circle);
            indices.Add(i + 2);
            indices.Add(i + 1);
        }

        // DRAW SIDES
        for(int i = 0; i < nb_vertices_per_circle; ++i){
            int next_index = (i + 1) % nb_vertices_per_circle;

            indices.Add(i);                                     // BOTTOM LEFT
            indices.Add( nb_vertices_per_circle + next_index);  // TOP RIGHT
            indices.Add(next_index);                            // BOTTOM RIGHT


            indices.Add(i);                                     // BOTTOM LEFT
            indices.Add(i + nb_vertices_per_circle);            // TOP LEFT
            indices.Add(nb_vertices_per_circle + next_index);   // TOP RIGHT
        }

        ibo = indices.ToArray();
    }

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected() //Draw the markers, if the object is selected
    { 
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        for (int i=0; i< mesh.vertices.Length; i++){
            Gizmos.color= new Color(((float)i)/mesh.vertices.Length,0, 0);
            Vector3    worldPos = transform.TransformPoint(mesh.vertices[i]);
            Gizmos.DrawCube(worldPos, Vector3.one * 0.1f);
        }
    }
}
```

`

With this code we can create a 3D shape like a cube or a cylinder but when we create our top and our base ( in DRAW TOP and DRAW BASE) it makes the normal looks weird and I dont understand why. Can you help me to understand it please ?
[our Normal problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC5CX.png)

We know that ussually people create their models in 3D software like blender but we really need to do it in unity for our project.

I've seen that if my normals are pointing to the top the face are too illuminated but when they are facing down it's too shady. To create our base and top shape, we have followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YG-gIX_OvSE)

Comment: Not sure if this makes a difference in your situation, but based on the documentation the tangents should be calculated after the normals.  `Tangents are calculated using the vertex positions, normals and texture coordinates of the Mesh.`

Comment: @hijinxbassist Oh thanks, i missed it ! Unfortunately it doesn't change anything, but it's still a good idea to do things in the right order.